# Firebase orderByChild not working in my Database

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a firebase database at this structure

```
DATA: { 
 DATE: {
  KEY: {
     NAME: "",
     AGE: "".
     ADDRESS: ""
     }
  } 
}
```

```js
    var ref = database.ref('DATA');
    ref.orderByChild('AGE').equalTo(AGE).on('child_added',
    function (snapshot) {
      console.log(snapshot.val());
          if (snapshot.exists()) {
            var content = '';
            snapshot.forEach(function (data) {
                 var val = data.val();
                 console.log(data.val());
                 content += '<tr>';

                 if (val.AGE) {
                      content += '<td><strong>' + val.AGE + '</strong></td>';
                      } else {
                      content += '<td>-</td>';
                      }
```

I tried to console log the snapshot.val but it shows null. How can I do this?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firebase queries work on a flat list of nodes, and the value you order/filter on must exist at a fixed location under each direct child node of the location you're querying.

If the `KEY` is always called `KEY`, you can query its `AGE` property with:

```
var ref = database.ref('DATA');
ref.orderByChild('KEY/AGE').equalTo(AGE)...
```

But if the `KEY` is actually a dynamic value, then the `AGE` is not in a fixed path for each child and you can't query on it.

In that case you'll have to restructure your data (or add an additional structure) for this use-case as shown in [Firebase Query Double Nested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27207059/firebase-query-double-nested) and in [Firebase query if child of child contains a value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40656589/firebase-query-if-child-of-child-contains-a-value).

Comment: Thank you. I think I need to work on the client side rendering.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
console.log(snapshot.val().AGE);
```